postfix mailing not working
I have a cron job and at the top have the
MAILTO=test@hotmail.com
after my cron jobs run i was hoping for an email but I receive nothing
Apr 29 10:00:01 momspi postfix/pickup[13242]: B432C89D70: uid=1000 from=<admin>
Apr 29 10:00:01 momspi postfix/cleanup[13329]: B432C89D70: message-id=<20240429170001.B432C89D70@mom0c14.ts.net>
Apr 29 10:00:01 momspi postfix/qmgr[13126]: B432C89D70: from=<admin@mom0c14.ts.net>, size=661, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 10:00:04 momspi postfix/smtp[13331]: B432C89D70: to=<test@hotmail.com>, relay=hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[52.101.194.18]:25, delay=2.3, d>
Apr 29 10:00:04 momspi postfix/cleanup[13329]: 049AF89D72: message-id=<20240429170004.049AF89D72@mom0c14.ts.net>
Apr 29 10:00:04 momspi postfix/qmgr[13126]: 049AF89D72: from=<>, size=3588, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 10:00:04 momspi postfix/bounce[13333]: B432C89D70: sender non-delivery notification: 049AF89D72
Apr 29 10:00:04 momspi postfix/qmgr[13126]: B432C89D70: removed
Apr 29 10:00:04 momspi postfix/local[13334]: 049AF89D72: to=<admin@mom10c14.ts.net>, relay=local, delay=0.04, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status>
Apr 29 10:00:04 momspi postfix/qmgr[13126]: 049AF89D72: removed

I have done some configuration here but im not sure its correct
main.cf
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 3.6 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 3.6



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_security_level=may

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = momspi.ta.ts.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = momspi.ta.ts.net, momspi, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname

i believe it should work with my freehostia account:
mbox.freehostia.com
I only need it to send (not receive)

Look at the full messages in the logs you've included here. The first entry from 10:00:04 has a refusal reason that has also been sent to your local system's root delivery account. Unfortunately it's not completely shown in your question

The most likely reason is that you're missing either authentication or a valid combination of DNS, DMARC, SPF and DKIM. You can't just throw an email out into the ether these days

Consider replacing postfix with msmtp

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/775551/msmtp-having-issues-authenticating
